# C# Dicom file is to big, how do i slim down?

Tags: c#, dicom, fo-dicom

Trying to embed a pdf into a dcm file by following the below gist. Our viewers don't support embedded pdf yet. The pdf is converted to an image by ghostscript and is 1000k on the disk (multi pages, 150 dpi).

https://gist.github.com/mdubey82/4030263

No matter what I do, `fo-dicom` takes a 1000k jpg or png or bmp file and creates a 11 meg dcm file.

Any ideas how to slim that down?

Thanks!

Edit

---

With lots help, here is a gist that builds a compressed dcm.

https://gist.github.com/WilliamDoman/e2365104f565a3bf9376fcec6609f432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The created DICOM files do not have compressed pixel data. That means that your PDF, which is probably JPEG/JPEG2000 compressed, is being decompressed and is creating a very large DICOM file. You want to look at the `ChangeTransferSyntax()` method to recompress the pixel data before saving.

```
DicomFile file = new DicomFile(dataset);
file.ChangeTransferSyntax(DicomTransferSyntax.JPEGProcess14SV1);
file.Save("dicom.dcm");
```

Comment: Your probably on the right track.  I think that syntax might be a different library than fo-dicom.  I'm using 2.0.2 version.  I'll see if I can find something similar.

Comment: That syntax has moved to an extension method in the namespace Dicom.Imaging.Codec, but it didn't have any affect on the size.  I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Are the _Dicom.Native.dll_ and/or _Dicom.Native64.dll_ files available in your path? Do you have a `LogManager` configured to ensure that there are no errors happening during the encoding process?

Comment: yes they are.   Didn't setup logging in my console app.  Will do it now.

Comment: created a gist, trying to get a simple jpg memory stream into the file.  builds small dcm but doesnt render image in viewer.  https://gist.github.com/WilliamDoman/1c8ad32559ccd5f658e50e48b3c66df0

Comment: omg, you were right, just a little different syntax.  The method returns a new instance.  This makes a 3000k file.   DicomFile dicomfile = new DicomFile(dataset);
            DicomFile compressed = dicomfile.ChangeTransferSyntax(DicomTransferSyntax.JPEGProcess14SV1);
            compressed.Save("dicomfile7.dcm");